# Babel Errors in Cloud 9 IDE

Tags: vue.js, cloud9-ide

Getting a bunch of babel errors when running `npm run dev` with the Vue cli.

[image]

This only happens in Cloud9.

Any thoughts on what could be the issue or how to disable errors like this before running `npm run dev`?

All babel related it looks like.

Comment: Have you tried clearing `node_modules` and install all over again?

Comment: For an Ubuntu instance/workspace: Check that npm and node is updated to latest version. Checkout [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for updating node. I'll check how it is working if you're creating a NodeJs workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't re-create the babel error messages but it's possible that it could be caused if npm/node is not up-to-date. (Vue-cli wasn't starting dev server before the installation below)

Is your repository public where you're getting the error messages? Then I could have a look at the errors.

If removing `node_modules` folder is not helping,
here is how you can create a new IDE workspace for vue.js ($ for commands in bash terminal):

1. Create a blank Ubuntu workspace
2. Check that nvm is installed & up-to-date with (check version of install script [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)):

   `$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash`
3. `$ nvm install node 6`
4. `$ npm i vue-cli -g`
5. `$ vue init webpack yourAppName`
6. `$ cd yourAppName`
7. `$ npm install`
8. `$ npm run dev`
9. Click preview to test that Vue server is running as expected

[Here](https://ide.c9.io/awolf81/nodejs_v6) is a link to a HelloWorld Vue app in cloud9 ide.

If you have an existing app you can also use git to clone it into your new workspace instead of creating a new app.